# Pandas checking if a column contains a 0 and another is not null

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set I am reading with csv file and I want to grab the row number/index where an if statement is true.

So if the column row value is 0 and another column value in the same row is not null.

Right now my loop is showing that all rows in my data set have a 0 and not null which is wrong, so its not working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
counter = 0

for index, row in raw_csv_data.iterrows():
    if(row['column1'] == 0 and row['column3'] != np.nan):
        print(row['column1'], row['column3'])
```

Solution fixed part of if statement

```
row.isna()['column3'] == False
```

Comment: `row['column1']==0 and ...`. But you'd better not running a `for` loop and just do `counter = (csv_data['column1'].eq(0) & csv_data['column3'].notna()).sum()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is this statement have syntactical issue, please check the below line of code and replace it with yous and then it will works for sure

```
if(row['column1'] == 0 and row['column3'] != np.nan)
```

below is your complete code

```
counter = 0

for index, row in raw_csv_data.iterrows():
    if(row['column1'] == 0 and row['column3'] != np.nan)
        counter += 1
```

Comment: send your output here

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is the following:

```
counts = sum((data['column1'].eq(0) & ~data['column3'].isna()))
```

`eq` is a method to check if the values are equal to 0 (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html))

Similarity, for `isna()` see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)

Comment: Im trying to get the row number for future use, the counter is just to check the total number so i can check if its correct